# .htaccess - redirect old urls to new urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect the old urls to new one:

www.bouda66.cz/?q=cs/tips_for_trips **to** www.bouda66.cz 
www.bouda66.cz/?q=cs/price_list **to** www.bouda66.cz 
www.bouda66.cz/?q=pl/price_list **to** www.bouda66.cz/pl
www.bouda66.cz/?q=pl/tips_for_trips **to** www.bouda66.cz/pl 
...

I have tried (but with no luck):
`Redirect 301 /?q=cs/tips_for_trips http://www.bouda66.cz`
`RewriteRule ^/?q=cs/tips_for_trips$ http://www.bouda66.cz? [L,R=301]`
`RewriteRule ^?q=cs/.*$ http://www.bouda66.cz [L,R=301]`

Here is my full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on    

# Add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]    

# If it is nested within a directory
RewriteBase /               

# Remove from url - index.php?page=
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [L,R=301]    

# Redirect for older pages
#Redirect 301 /?q=cs/tips_for_trips http://www.bouda66.cz
#RewriteRule ^/?q=cs/tips_for_trips$ http://www.bouda66.cz? [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^?q=cs/.*$ http://www.bouda66.cz [L,R=301] - error 500    

# Ignore all real directors
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Ignore all real files (php scripts, images, styles)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Urls to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml$
# everything else will generate index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]    

DirectorySlash Off
```

Can you help me?
Thanks
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to rewrite a URL based upon the query string you need to use a `RewriteCond`. When using `RewriteRule` the query string is not part of what it's matching. This is why you need to use the `RewriteCond`.

This checks that the query string contains q=cs/{anything} and then anything after that. It will redirect to www.example.com.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=cs/(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
```

This checks that the query string contains q=pl/{anything} and then anything after that. It will redirect to www.example.com/pl.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=pl/(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/pl? [R=301,L]
```

You can test .htaccess rules out on http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and advice. It works perfectly!